# How can I count the number of positions where both my vectors have a given value?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Say `A` and `B` are 2 vectors where `length(A) = length(B)`.
All elements of `A` and `B` are either `0` or `1`. How can I count in 1 line the number of positions where both vectors have the value `1`?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the list of solutions, you can also do the dot-product, which will give you the answer:

```
C=A'*B;            %'# here I've assumed A & B are both column vectors
```

This is also by far the ***fastest*** of the solutions posted.

**Timing test**

```
A=round(rand(1e5,1));
B=round(rand(1e5,1));
```

*Dot-product*

```
tic;for i=1:1e4;A'*B;end;toc                                                       %'SO formatting
Elapsed time is 0.621839 seconds.
```

*nnz*

```
tic;for i=1:1e4;nnz(A&B);end;toc
Elapsed time is 14.572747 seconds.
```

*sum(bitand())*

```
tic;for i=1:1e4;sum(bitand(A,B));end;toc
Elapsed time is 64.111025 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

One of many solutions, using `nnz` instead of `sum` to find the number of non-zero elements:

```
nnz(A&B)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sum(bitand(A, B))
```